# How does a bubble pop?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics, surface-tension, bubbles

I was looking at some old [slow motion videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLR-LT55Ueo) showing a phenomenon where a bubble is popped by firing a sphere (or pea) through it.

One obvious thing that happens is that the pea does not pop the bubble immediately, it goes through the first side and then only bursts the bubble when going out the other side.

Is there some intuition about how this is supposed to work?  Is it that the air flows in when the first hole appears and then flows back out of the second hole so that there is some type of pressure difference?

Comment: I think it is more easily explained by surface tension. As the pea enters the bubble, due to the speed of the pea and the surface tension of the bubble, the "entrance wound" is proportional to the size of the pea, and the bubble recovers from the rupture as the surface of the bubble retracts. As the pea exits, the rupture ís much larger and outwards so it is not possible for the bubble to "heal back".

Comment: But why is the rupture bigger on the way out?

Comment: I think it is because the rupture direction: If the rupture is "inwards", the recovery is otuwards in the direction of the film as the pea enters, and the bubble can recover. If the rupture is outwards, as the bubble breaks the rupture is outwards and the recovery is not possible since the rupture distance is too large for the bubble surface to return.

Comment: I've seen peas or round objects pop the bubble on initial impact. I can't remember where I read it but if the object is dipped in the bubble solution prior to launch so that it has a thin soap film then it is more likely to pass through the bubble and pop on the second impact. I'm sorry I can't remember the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your video, when the object first touches the bubble, it **creates a hole on one side**. However, the elasticity of the bubble's surface causes it to contract and partially seal around the object. As the object moves through the bubble, it displaces some of the air within it. This displacement leads to a **temporary increase in pressure inside** the bubble. The increase in pressure inside the bubble causes air to flow towards the newly created hole. This **inward airflow** helps maintain the integrity of the bubble by preventing it from bursting immediately. Once the object exits through the opposite side of the bubble, the sudden release of pressure causes the bubble to burst. The airflow dynamics change as the pressure equalizes, and the bubble can no longer sustain its shape.

Comment: If the object has high adhesion with the bubble it will pop on the initial impact due to friction. Wetting the surface of the object with bubble solution prior to launch lowers the adhesion so the bubble can seal around the object with minimal friction.

Comment: Can the increase in pressure inside the bubble be quantified, I guess it will be increased both by the speed and size of the sphere?

Comment: Yes, A faster-moving object will displace more air, leading to a larger pressure increase. Similarly, a larger object will displace a greater volume of air, resulting in a higher pressure increase.
However, quantifying the exact increase in pressure can be challenging as it depends on the specific characteristics of the bubble and the object, as well as the precise dynamics of the interaction. 
Did I understand your question correctly? @Tom